# Рефакторинг при работе с массивом

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть двумерный массив (заменить его на трехмерный не могу, т.к. это намного усложнит другой кой код):

```
let array = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             [1,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6],
             [7,8,9,7,8,9,1,2,3]];
```

Необходимо найти дубликаты в блоках этого массива. Блок это 3x3 ячейки взятые из массива. Т.е. в `array`есть три блока

```
                          1,2,3  4,5,6  7,8,9
                          1,5,6  1,2,3  4,5,6
                          7,8,9  7,8,9  1,2,3
```

Как видно в первом блоке имеется дубликат, для его определения я делаю следующее:

**1)** Определяю блок в зависимости от значения координаты в массиве.

```
let storeOfCoord = {
  0: ['00','01','02','10','11','12','20','21','22'],
  1: ['03','04','05','13','14','15','23','24','25'],
  2: ['06','07','08','16','17','18','26','27','28']
}; 

for (let key in storeOfCoord) {
  if (storeOfCoord[key].includes(x+''+y)) {
    return detectRegion(key);
  }
}
```

**2)** Определив координату, я понимаю какой блок мне нужно взять для поиска в нем дубликата.

```
function detectRegion(key) {
  switch(key) {
   case '0':
       return sliceConcat(0, 0, 3);
       break;
   case '1':
       return sliceConcat(0, 3, 6);
       break;
   case '2':
       return sliceConcat(0, 6, 9);
       break;
   default:
       break;
  }
};
```

**3)** Склеиваю массив и различных "кусочков", которые распиханы по разным массивам.

```
function sliceConcat(i, from, to) {
  return self.findDuplicates(temp[i].slice(from,to).concat(temp[i+1].slice(from,to).concat(temp[i+2].slice(from,to))));
};
```

**4)** Наконец получив блок в виде массива, я могу пройтись по нему функцией и узнать есть ли в нем дубликаты. Т.о. Пройдясь по всему массиву `array` я увижу, есть ли в нем дубликаты.

```
  function findDuplicates(array) {
    let dup = [];
    array = array.sort();
    array.map((elem, i, a) => {
      if (a[i+1] == a[i] && a[i] !== ' ') {
        (dup.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) ? dup.push(a[i]) : []
      }
    });
    return dup;
  }
```

Решение очень топорное и длинное, как его можно укоротить и упростить. 
[Рабочий пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zecukupupa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: *есть двумерный массив* Откуда такое чудо? Постановка задачи кагбэ требует, просто вопиёт - преобразуйте его в трёхмерный... и желательно ещё на стадии создания.

Comment: Если важен только факт наличия дубликатов, а не конкретные значения, то `findDuplicates` можно сократить до чего-то такого: `function findDuplicates(array) {return array.some((val, i, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(val) !== i)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял задачу: даны некие координаты x,y, по ним нужно определить, в каком они блоке, и для этого блока проверить на наличие дубликатов.

В таком случае (для блоков 3x3) можно делать так. Стартовые координаты блока:

```
x0 = x  - (x % 3)
y0 = y  - (y % 3)
```

Далее используем set и в двойном цикле *(как его лучше в JS организовать?)* вносим в него элементы блока

```
let set = new Set();
for (iy = y0; iy < y0 + 3; iy++) {
   for (ix = x0; ix < x0 + 3; ix++) {
       set.add(array[iy][ix]);
   }
}
```

И проверяем, что размер set ровно 9